# java - how can i edit the form's height/width (I use Netbeans)

Tags: java, forms, netbeans

I try to create a simple program where, from click a button i could size by height?
Ex. :i create a text field, a button. If In a text field i write 255, form's height of the form expands by 255.

Thanks

Comment: post the effort. and tell specifically where have you stucked?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be that hard, right? Add an `ActionListener` to the button, and when the button is clicked, retrieve the integer from the textfield and use it to set the form's height/width.